# Why && return true and and return false?

Tags: php

In this example:

```
$x = $b && $c;
$y = $b and $c;
```

Why $x = true and $y = false ? are && not equal and  ?

Comment: So what language is this? Java, JS or PHP?

Comment: There is no keyword "and" in java...

Comment: this not is java, not is javascript

Comment: @jPO ['and' is valid](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP:
The first code will set $x to the result of the comparison $b with $c, both have to be true,
The second code will set $y like $b and thant , compare the success of this with the value of $c

Answer (score 0):

The precedence of operators is what makes the difference here.

[PHP Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

[JavaScript Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)